# AngularJS - Filter nested object in Javascript

Tags: angularjs, filter

I've a nested object as following:

```
[
  {
    "$id": "25",
    "Field": {
      "$id": "26",
      "Key": "bb3927b1-fcbb-4fc4-8eff-24b7a20fad7b",
      "EntityKey": "e904000c-b0b8-49ca-8a49-42a2e5b5d295",
      "PostalCode": "12345",
      "City": "My city1"
    },
    "EntityId": "MyEntity"
  },
  {
    "$id": "27",
    "Field": {
      "$id": "28",
      "Key": "ad4f2cb5-7397-474d-aed7-ff4bcc14d292",
      "EntityKey": "e904000c-b0b8-49ca-8a49-42a2e5b5d295",
      "PostalCode": "67890",
      "City": "My city2"
    },
    "EntityId": "MyEntity"
  }
]
```

In my HTML page, I'd like to filter by PostalCode or City:

```
<select ng-model="filterBy" ng-init="filterBy='EntityId'">
  <option value="EntityId">Entity</option>
  <option value="Field.PostalCode">PostalCode</option>
  <option value="Field.City">City</option>
</select>
<input type="text" ng-model="query[filterBy]" autofocus />
```

Using the function in JavaScript:

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

I can see only EntityId which is working, but not the others fields.

P.S: I know how to use it in HTML binding:

```
    | filter: {Field: {City: 'my-value'}}
```

My intention is to do the same using the filter in JavaScript.

Thanks for your help.

Omar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, which part of what you've tried doesn't work?
Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/c5wW9UEhT4pkrBPEH5ke?p=preview) that demonstrates the filter both in html and js.

```
$scope.filteredList = $filter('filter')($scope.list, {
  Field: {Name: 'City'}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer o4ohel! In fact, how can I pass to my JS function dynamically the object: Field: {Name: 'City'}

From a select/option for example:

<select ng-model="filterBy" ng-init="filterBy='EntityId'">
  <option value="EntityId">Entity</option>
  <option value="Field.PostalCode">PostalCode</option>
  <option value="Field.City">City</option>
</select>
<input type="text" ng-model="query[filterBy]" autofocus />

Comment: @OmarAMRANI : I've updated the plnkr with 2 caveats: * I don't know if that's what you were looking for. * Without understanding your full intent, it seems like an overly complex solution.

Comment: I'm note sure if the Plunker is updated. I'm getting always the same version.. Could you pls send me the new link? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$filter` like this to match to all fields, deeply:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.unfilteredList, {$: '67890'});
```

Or use a function:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.unfilteredList, function(fullObject){
  // assuming $scope.filterBy contains the string `PostalCode`
  return fullObject.Field[$scope.filterBy] === '67890';
});
```

Comment: Thanks Boris, that helps as well!